# Transform a pairwise column in a data matrix R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a table, tab separate and pairwise:

```
Names  Col  Times
A      B     12
B      C     13
C      D     14
A      C     15
B      D     16
A      D     17
```

My plan is to create a heatmap, but I need format my table as:

```
        A    B    C   D
   A    0    NA   NA  NA
   B    12   0    NA  NA
   C    15   13   0   NA
   D    17   16   14  0
```

My initial data frame is very big and I would like to know how I can format it in R.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the igraph package:

```
library(igraph)
G <- graph.data.frame(df,directed=FALSE)
A <- as_adjacency_matrix(G,names=TRUE,sparse=FALSE,attr="Times",type='lower')

   A  B  C D
A  0  0  0 0
B 12  0  0 0
C 15 13  0 0
D 17 16 14 0
```

Hope this helps!